# input blob is null in azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function and i would like to have an input blob in my azure function and then when i read it in c# code the input parameter is null.

Here is the function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "path": "mystorageacountname/containername/file.csv",
      "connection": "mofunctions_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

C# code is printing null:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string inputBlob, TraceWriter log)
{
// trying to print the name of inputBlob variable
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "blob", inputBlob);



}
```

Any help is appreciate it?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good in your example except the path to Blob. There's no need to specify `mystorageacountname` in the path. I copy-pasted your function and changed the path to `containername/file` and it works just fine.